# Retrieving a single object of interest rather than Blog.objects.all() in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework, django-class-based-views

I am comfortable using **Class Based View** in **Django/DRF** rahter than functional views. But I think my database hits is tremendously increased thus resulting my API to become slow. For eg:

I have an endpoint which updates or deletes the concern object of which the id is sent in the url. My view looks like this.

```
class UpdateOrderView(UpdateAPIView,DestroyAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]    
    queryset = Order.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OrderUpdateSerializer

    def perform_destroy(self, instance):
        instance.delete()
```

As we can see above, my queryset is all the objects from Order table. If I print the queryset, it gives all the objects from the Order table which makes it slow.

**My url is:**

```
path('api/updateorder/<int:pk>',views.UpdateOrderView.as_view(),name ='api-updateorder'),
```

**How can I get just the particular object here using id?**

In a functional view, we can do this.

```
def Update_or_delete(request,pk)
```

But, pk is not recognized in the class-based view.

**My serializer:**

```
class OrderUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    order_items = OrderItemUpdateSerializer(many=True)
    billing_details = BillingDetailsSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['id','ordered','order_status','order_items','total_price','billing_details']



    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        # billing_details_data = validated_data.pop('billing_details', None)
        # order_items_data = validated_data.pop('order_items')

        #instance = super(OrderUpdateSerializer, self).update(instance,validated_data)
        #print(instance)
        instance.order_status = validated_data.get('order_status')
        instance.ordered = validated_data.get('ordered')

        #billing_details_logic

        billing_details_data = validated_data.pop('billing_details',None)
        if billing_details_data is not None:
            instance.billing_details.address = billing_details_data['address']
            instance.billing_details.save()


        #order_items_logic

        instance.save()
    #instance.order_items.clear()
    order_items_data = validated_data.pop('order_items')
    print(order_items_data)

   
    for order_item_data in order_items_data:
        oi, created = OrderItem.objects.update_or_create(
            id = order_item_data['id'],

            defaults={
                'quantity' : order_item_data['quantity'],
                'order_item_status': order_item_data['order_item_status']
            }

        )             
    instance.save()
    return super().update(instance,validated_data)
```

**2. My second question is this.**

Many senior developers are a fan of using APIView in Django Rest Framework instead of using Generic Class Based Views because one can write custom code inside APIView more rather than in CBV. For eg all CRUD APIs can be integrated into a single API under APIView.

**Is the above statement actually true?? So, should I stop using CBV and move to APIView instead? I need a clear explanation.**

Comment: What is the url serving this view? Is pk part of it?

Comment: I have added my url in the code. Yes i have pk passed as a parameter.

Comment: Show `OrderUpdateSerializer` (and the `Order` model) that queryset would not slow you down as you are dealing with only single objects (`UpdateAPIView` and `DestroyAPIView` deal with single objects)

Comment: If i do a print command after queryset, it prints all objects ie i am querying over the whole table and bring all the objects. Is it not?? @AbdulAzizBarkat

Comment: @Django-Rocks `QuerySet`s are _lazy_ hence no database query is made until it is actually needed. Since your view deals with a single object only it should call `filter` or `get` on this queryset to get only the relevant objects, hence likely you show _nested_ objects in your serializer which is what slows you down.

Comment: Hello @AbdulAzizBarkat, I have added my serializer class. You can check it. Also, can you answer my second question please?

Comment: @Django-Rocks see `OrderItemUpdateSerializer(many=True)` this implies one extra query to fetch these related objects, you likely also have _another_ nested serializer in that please show that too, plus your models for these too.

Answer (score 1):

"But, pk is not recognized in the class-based view."

thats simply not the case. You can capture url parameters just like function based views.

Parameters passed in the url in django are captured and stored in a `kwargs` dictionary-like object which you can access in your view CLASS BASED views. simply call

```
value = self.kwargs.get(key)
```

or

```
value = self.kwargs['pk]
```

in your case.
if you write your own get/post methods , you can accept the arguments you need without going through kwargs.
for ex

```
class ProcessRequest(APIview):
   def get(self, request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
      # do some work
      pass
```

Comment: Hello @joel, self is not recognised inside class based view. I have to define a function again.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are not using DRF router for your url routing? [Routers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/)

This router class has a lot of good features to handle different endpoints including extracting pk in cases it needed.

Comment: I dont like using viewsets and modelviewsets. I like using class based view. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use rest-framework  APIView class then you can do whatever you want with that follow below example:

```
class FooBarView(APIView):
    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        obj_pk = kwargs.get('pk')
        queryset = FooBarModel.objects.filter(pk=obj_pk).first()
        serialized_data = FoobarSerializer(queryset)
        return Response(serialized_data)




class FoobarViewSet(
    viewsets.GenericViewSet,
):

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        return FoobarSerializer

    def get_serializer_context(self):
        return {"request": self.request, "args": self.args, "kwargs": self.kwargs}

    def get_queryset(self):
        obj_id = self.kwargs.get('pk')

        queryset = Foobar.objects.filter(pk=obj_id)
        return queryset
```

For your second question you can actually write custom code in Serializer also. Sometimes using ViewSets make more sense and some time APIView.
It's depends on task you are handling.